# trying to install mongodb via npm and getting EINVAL errors

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to install packages using NPM. For example I'm trying to get install mongodb on ubuntu 14.04 by the usual

```
Sudo npm install mongodb
```

I get this error

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/cougs/.npm/mongodb/2.0.45/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "mongodb"
npm ERR! node v4.1.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! path  /mnt/nfs_data/byucougars.com/RebelFleet/app/node_modules/mongodb/package.json
npm ERR! code EINVAL
npm ERR! errno -22
npm ERR! syscall chown

npm ERR! EINVAL: invalid argument, chown    '/mnt/nfs_data/byucougars.com/RebelFleet/app/node_modules/mongodb/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /mnt/nfs_data/byucougars.com/RebelFleet/app/npm-debug.log
```

I'm pretty sure it's a permission issue with my user. probably when I copied stuff to the server via FTP, it screwed things up stuff. I just have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: `Sudo` with capital `S`? Also, why don't you use `apt`? [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Sorry, capital S in Sudo was just a typing error when writing this out. Yeah apt-get works, but I am using nodejs and no matter which npm package I try to install I get this error. I would like to correct it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this would be to override *chown()* by LD_PRELOAD to interpose a function which always returns zero ("success"). So instead of

```
#npm install
```

you would do

```
#echo "int chown() { return 0; }" > preload.c && gcc -shared -o preload.so preload.c 
#LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/preload.so npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my code was running on a MNT nfs server using version 4.0. Which changes all permissions to nobody and it was causing the issue to repeat every time I try to fix it. So I just migrated the code back to the original server and it worked fine after that.